# ASP.NET handler not running on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0, module, asp.net-4.0

I've wrote a simple handler:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        byte[] imgData = context.Session["Data"] as byte[];

        if (imgData != null)
        {
            context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

            context.Response.BinaryWrite(imgData);
            context.Response.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And setup the `web.config`:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="image.png" type="TestWeb.Handlers.ImageHandler, TestWeb" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Image" verb="GET" path="image.png" type="TestWeb.Handlers.ImageHandler, TestWeb" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

- If I run the code **allowing VS start a new IIS service** and open a new tab **it reaches the breakpoint** on the handler.
- If I set `don't open a page. Wait for request from an external application` it **never reaches the handler**.

It is not just the breakpoint, no code from the handler executes when I run the website configured on IIS. It only works if I start from VS.

[image: only from VS]

**What did I miss when configuring IIS7 ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to switch the Application Pool to `Integrated` mode, it was using classic.

And I had to remove the handler configuration from `<system.web>` because it was giving me `error 500.23`.

> HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server
>   Error An ASP.NET setting has been
>   detected that does not apply in
>   Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Comment: You can have the config in both places if you add <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> under <System.WebServer>

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach to the asp.net worker process. go to tools/attach to process and choose the w3p process.

Comment: It's not just the breakpoint. No code from the handler executes. I don't think the problem is on VS, I guess it's something on IIS7.